# SQL subquery - select data from two tables

Tags: sql, subquery

A simple SQL query, but I can't get it to work.
When I delete the subquery the statement returns correct data so 
the error needs to be in the subquery.
Here is what I got so far:

```
"SELECT s.*, (SELECT s.* FROM sites_photos WHERE sites_id = s.id)
 FROM sites
 AS s";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't get an error message or anything?  Pretty sure subqueries can only return one row and when you use them like this, one column

Comment: This one can't work. what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a nested select, you can only have one column.  This is called a "scalar subquery".  If you want multiple columns, just use a `join`:

```
SELECT s.*, sp.*
FROM sites s left join
     sites_photos sp
     on sp.sites_id = s.id;
```

Note the use of `left join`.  This ensures that all sites are included even when there are no matching rows in `sites_photos`.